# Instead of using Builder pattern, why can't I just create an object and set its fields directly as follows?

Tags: java

Why can't I just do

```
Animal object = new Animal();
object.setType("cat");
object.setName("Meow");
```

instead of

```
Animal.Builder objectBuilder = new Animal.Builder();
Animal object = objectBuilder.setType("cat").setName("Meow").build();
```

or

```
Animal object = new Animal.Builder().setType("cat").setName("Meow").build();
```

All three ways end up creating an `Animal` object with type cat and name Meow, no? Are the latter methods superior to the first one? If I use the first way, I don't have to create a separate Builder class and I can just use getters and setters.

Comment: Because you should not have an animal without a name and a type.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416239/setters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaWorld on OO: Getters/Setters vs Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927292/javaworld-on-oo-getters-setters-vs-builder)

Comment: If you want to make your Object immutable after calling `.build()` then Builder Pattern is for you.

Answer (score 2):

The builder pattern saves you time writing code!

Notice how you need to write the word `object` many many times if you used setters to set the properties? With the builder pattern, you don't need to write `object` every time. This is especially helpful if your variable names are long.

More importantly though, the builder pattern helps you create immutable objects. [Immutable objects are generally considered a good thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769607/why-do-we-need-immutable-class) You see, the `Builder` object is not actually immutable, but once you call `build()`, the return value can be immutable. If you don't use the builder pattern and wants to create something immutable you have to put all the property values in the constructor:

```
new MyObject("some string", 10, true, 0.5)
```

And you would have no idea what each parameter is for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use builder pattern when the object is complex and has lot of attributes. Builder pattern helps to create objects with different initialization attributes quickly. Imagine having an class with 10 attributes and every time you have to initialize all the 10 attributes. With Builder you can have default values for few attributes so that you don't have to initialize all the attributes every time.

**Example**:

```
public class AnimalBuillder {

  private String category = "Domestic" // default initialization
  private String type;
  private String name;

  AnimalBuilder withCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
    return this;
  }

  AnimalBuilder withName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  AnimalBuilder withType(String type) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  Animal build() {
    return new Animal(name, type, category);
  }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
new AnimalBuilder().withType("cat").withName("meow").build();
```

OR

```
new AnimalBuilder().withCategory("wild").withType("cat").withName("meow").build();
```

depending on how well you provide default initialization you can create objects with different attributes quickly with very few chain methods using a builder.

Comment: Thanks @Bentaye for your editing. I am getting use to formatting on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: consider the following code.

```
Animal object = new Animal();
object.setType("cat");
// lots of code
object.setType("dog");
```

Now, your cat suddenly changed into a dog. This is obviously not something you want.

You don't *have* to use the Builder pattern, but it's a proven [Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) to make an object immutable. Some languages, such as C#, provide some syntactic sugar so that you don't have to write a builder class, but the principle is the same.